# Change default program

Tags: default-programs

I know that this question was also asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457579/how-do-i-set-default-programs), but I have a slightly different problem.

I want to open CSV files using sublime instead of Calc.

However, sublime does not even appear to my applications, when I follow the procedure at mentioned at that answer, in order to select that as default.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition with Unity.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try clicking on the "Show other applications" button that's shown in the dialog?

Comment: yes @terdon. I have tried that, and it is not shown there. The fact is that I am searching for a way to add sublime at the "other applications" list

Answer (score 2):

OK, the answer was at [this post](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/). What should be done is to execute the following command:

> gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop

find the `exec` line:

> Exec=sublime

and add an `"%f"` next to it

> Exec=sublime %f

In any case sublime can be replaced by the program you want to add to the applications list.